# Deploying contract to infura via @truffle/hdwallet-provider is hanging

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, infura, web3-providers

I created a contract and deployed to Ganache test network successfully but it is not deploying to  infura.

```
//this section is clean. worked for Ganache
var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
const interface = output.contracts["test.sol"]["Inbox"].abi;
const bytecode = output.contracts["test.sol"]["Inbox"].evm.bytecode.object
```

for infura,

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");

const Web3 = require("web3");
const compile = require("./compile");

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  "chef punch git then seek hobby abstract sad split fog quick able",
  "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/87773d0063ddee33821710c0e926c554"
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  console.log("attemtign", accounts);// shows the array of accounts
  const myContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(interface)
    .deploy({ data: "0x" + bytecode, arguments: ["hi there"] })
    .send({
      gas: "1000000",
      from: accounts[0],
      gasPrice: "10000" // even i discarded here did not work
    });
  console.log(myContract.options.address);
  provider.engine.stop();
};

deploy();
```

I have 3 eth in my account and terminal is showing this `console.log("attemtign", accounts)` then hanging.

Answer (score 0):

The gas price is too low. As of 2020-04-01 from rinkeby.etherscan.com gas prices are around 1 gwei = "1000000000" wei.

To have faster confirmation times adjust to a higher value.

Transactions are processed in increasing order of their nonce. A pending transaction with low fees will prevent new transaction with corrects fees from being mined.

Comment: I get this error when I placed the value above :"RuntimeError: abort(Error: exceeds block gas limit). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info."

Comment: @Yilmaz You have to set gasPrice to 1000000000, it seems you were setting gas instead.

Comment: gasPrice: 1000000000 or       gasPrice: "1000000000", still hanging. If i add  gas:100  i get this:abort(Error: intrinsic gas too low).  if add       gas: 1000000000,
abort(Error: exceeds block gas limit).

Comment: @Yilmaz Does the account used have a pending transaction? gas depends on the contract size. You haven't put the code in the question so I can't say a number. A typical contract requires less than 5000000 but complex ones will use more.

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.0-alpha/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=deploy#id9
.You can try printing error,transaction hash or receipt. It might help you figure out the actual problem, since it gets stuck after 
 *console.log("attemtign", accounts)*.